# Retrieve list of all available printer drivers (like the Add Printer Wizard)

Tags: c#, printing, driver

In c# I would get a list of all the printer drivers installed on running system, like  the Windows ["add printer" wizard](http://maths-old.anu.edu.au/itdocs/lib/exe/fetch.php/printing%3awin-printer-wizard-select-make-model.png):

I've been able to list already installed printers, but how do I list the drivers available on the system?

Comment: This wizard does *not* list installed printer drivers, it includes drivers that *could* be installed.  This kind of functionality is buried in the Setup API.  Very hard to use from .NET, the pinvoke is nasty.  And it is *not* a simple API to use in general.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I think I'd rather avoid...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx
With this you can get installed printers.

Comment: This retrieves a list of installed printers, not the available drivers.

Comment: Or you dont want get installed printers, but all available?

Answer (score 0):

This code enumerates the installed printer drivers:

```
public struct DRIVER_INFO_2
{
    public uint cVersion;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string pName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string pEnvironment;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string pDriverPath;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string pDataFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string pConfigFile;
}


public static class EnumeratePrinterDriverNames
{
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int EnumPrinterDrivers(String pName, String pEnvironment, uint level, IntPtr pDriverInfo,
        uint cdBuf, ref uint pcbNeeded, ref uint pcRetruned);

    public static IEnumerable<string> Enumerate()
    {
        const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;

        uint needed = 0;
        uint returned = 0;
        if (EnumPrinterDrivers(null, null, 2, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref needed, ref returned) != 0)
        {
            //succeeds, but shouldn't, because buffer is zero (too small)!
            throw new ApplicationException("EnumPrinters should fail!");
        }

        int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (lastWin32Error != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(lastWin32Error);
        }

        IntPtr address = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr) needed);
        try
        {
            if (EnumPrinterDrivers(null, null, 2, address, needed, ref needed, ref returned) == 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            var type = typeof (DRIVER_INFO_2);
            IntPtr offset = address;
            int increment = Marshal.SizeOf(type);

            for (uint i = 0; i < returned; i++)
            {
                var di = (DRIVER_INFO_2) Marshal.PtrToStructure(offset, type);
                offset += increment;

                yield return di.pName;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(address);
        }
    }
}
```